# Direct vs Indirect searches

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, terminology, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model

In particle physics, when talking about the Standard Model and Beyond the Standard Model searches and theories, often one speaks about *direct* and *indirect* methods.

It is not clear to me where the difference lies, when one method is better then another and what are some examples of such methods being used today. I haven't found a document which clearly denotes the differences between the two.

Comment: @rfl Annav and sohail answered my question! From the prospective of dark matter I can imagine what direct and indirect should mean!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct search is a data analysis for finding the evidence of a particular particle exhibiting certain predicted properties. For example at the LHC the Higgs boson search. You put enormous energy, and hope that the particle will be produced and detected (distinguished clearly from the background).
An indirect search is basically search for evidence that the current prediction or precision of a certain measurement does not hold. For example using a lepton collider, to study deviations from the predictions of standard model. This divergence will indicate the existence of *new physics* or as we call it *beyond standard model* physics, but to exactly detect a particle, one will need to apply the theoretical explanation of the observed divergence. An example: The electroweak couplings of the top quark may diverge from the standard model predictions. Randall-Sundrum Models explain what could that imply for BSM.

Comment: Thank you very much! This explains a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_model) is a mathematical model and can make predictions for new particles to be found in searches in acceleration experiments, using the invariant mass of the particles. That is the way the expected Higgs particle of the Higgs mechanism was discovered.

In the standard model there are calculation of various quantities from the crossections to the expected within the present standard model [group structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_model) of the masses of particles.

If any measurements differ from the SM calculations more the 5  standard deviations  the situation requires a modification of the standard model, or even a new larger model to which the standard model will be an approximation. There can be theories where this newly discovered discrepancy can be attributed to a new particle. This is an indirect search and measurement. Looking for discrepancies to the standard model calculations is an indirect way for searching for new physics.

A good current example of an indirect measurement that is becoming a search for new particles is the observed violation of [lepton flavor universality](https://home.cern/news/news/physics/intriguing-new-result-lhcb-experiment-cern). Already there are proposals for [extensions of the standard model](https://physicsworld.com/a/has-a-new-particle-called-a-leptoquark-been-spotted-at-cern/) that claim it as the result of the existence of leptoquarks, sought unsuccessfully in invariant mass distributions.

> One tantalizing explanation is the existence of a hypothetical particle called a leptoquark, which is a massive boson that couples to both leptons and quarks. In principle, leptoquarks could have different coupling strengths to electrons and muons.

This, if validated, would be an indirect measurement of the existence of the leptoquark, and requires a new "Standard Model"

Comment: Thank you very much, anna. This makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 2):

A direct search looks for real particles:  on mass shell, with decay products whose energies-momenta combine to give the particle mass.

An indirect search looks for virtual particles: produced off mass shell in collisions or decays but not appearing in the final state.

As an example: the Z boson was 'discovered' indirectly by neutral current neutrino scattering and later 'discovered' directly by its production in proton/antiproton collisions at UA1 and UA2 experiments at CERN.

Comment: Ok, that makes it more clear as to why we use the name *direct* and *indirect*. Thank you!